# Find and replace in config file powershell or batch file

Tags: powershell, file, batch-file, editing

Say I have a config file that looks like this:

```
{name1}
Settinga=1
settingb=2
settingc=3
{name2}
Settinga=1
settingb=2
settingc=3
{name3}
Settinga=1
settingb=2
settingc=3
```

I want to be able to change the line settingb=2 under {name3} to another value such as settingb=4

It would be a file store on a Windows OS so ideally it would be done under PowerShell or batch command.

Anyone have any ideas or if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: what have u tried? in batch, you can use `=` as a delimiter and keep track of each line's value if it is `{name3}`

Comment: Please regard that this site is not a free code/script writing service but a resource for specific programming-related questions and answers! Please (re-)take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask] here! Also please go through [mcve]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do read your config file using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7), and store the section content under each name in a nested hash table, where the name lines are outer keys, and the settings lines are split into keys and values of an inner hash table. To maintain order of keys found from the original file, we can make use of [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1). To create one, simply add the `[ordered]` attribute to a hashtable `@{}`. You can find out more at [`about_Hash_Tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7#creating-ordered-dictionaries).

We can also use [`System.String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) to split the lines by `=`, which will use the length to determine if the line is a name or a setting. Length of 1 is a name and length of 2 is a setting.

```
# Read lines from config file
$config = Get-Content -Path .\config.txt

# Use an ordered hashtable to remember order of keys inserted
$sections = [ordered]@{}

# Keep a key which indicates the current name being added
$currentKey = $null

# Go through each line in the config file
foreach ($line in $config) {

    # Split each line by '='
    $items = $line.Split("=")

    # If splitted items is only one value, we found a new name
    # Set the new name and create an inner settings dictionary
    if ($items.Length -eq 1) {
        $currentKey = $line
        $sections[$currentKey] = [ordered]@{}
    }

    # Otherwise we found a normal line
    else {

        # Only add the setting if the current name is not null
        if ($null -ne $currentKey) {
            $sections[$currentKey][$items[0]] = $items[1]
        }
    }
}
```

Which will give a hash table `$sections` that looks like the following:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
{name1}                        {Settinga, settingb, settingc}
{name2}                        {Settinga, settingb, settingc}
{name3}                        {Settinga, settingb, settingc}
```

Then you could set a value(or multiple values) like this:

```
$sections["{name3}"].settingb = 4
```

And write the updated hash table to a output file using [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7). To iterate the outer and inner hash tables, we need to iterate their key value pairs with [`System.Collections.Hashtable.GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.getenumerator?view=netcore-3.1).

```
& {
    # Output each outer key first, where the names are stored
    foreach ($outerKvp in $sections.GetEnumerator()) {
        $outerKvp.Key

        # Then output each setting and value
        foreach ($innerKvp in $outerKvp.Value.GetEnumerator()) {
            "$($innerKvp.Key)=$($innerKvp.Value)"
        }
    }

# Pipe output from script block to output file
} | Out-File -FilePath .\output.txt
```

The above wraps the `foreach` loops inside a [`Call Operator &`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#call-operator-) to run the script block and pipe the output to `Out-File`. You can have a a look at [`about_Pipelines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7) and [`about_Script_Blocks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7) for more information.

Since I mentioned pipelines and script blocks, we can also use of [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7) to pass input down the pipeline. From some initial testing it seems this is slightly slower than the above solution(will need to investigate further with larger inputs). You can have a look at this [Runtime of Foreach-Object vs Foreach loop](http://Runtime%20of%20Foreach-Object%20vs%20Foreach%20loop) question for the differences between both approaches.

```
$sections.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Key
    $_.Value.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)"
    }
} | Out-File -FilePath .\output.txt
```

And finally the newly created output file below.

**output.txt**

```
{name1}
Settinga=1
settingb=2
settingc=3
{name2}
Settinga=1
settingb=2
settingc=3
{name3}
Settinga=1
settingb=4
settingc=3
```

Which shows `settingb` for `{name3}` was updated from `2` from `4`.